# Is there any way to associate file upload with a particular model in loopback 3?

Tags: loopbackjs

I am uploading file on this /api/containers/container/upload but I want to upload file using /api/Profile/upload. Is this possible ? Is there any way to automatically associate uploading file name with field created on Profile model ? 
For example, if I am uploading file name "abc.txt", it gets automatically uploaded to server and it also inserts/updates field "image_name" on Profile model.
I am new to loopback Pls help.

-

-

-

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by adding 'after remote method' hook, or 'after save' hook, so after upload and before the response is returned (or after your container was saved) you could process it and do something, like for example saving the profile picture. You can find more about that [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html) and [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html).